# Error for using declare reference parameter

Tags: c

I write a C program mentioned below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int&, int*);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int array[]     = {1,2,3};
    int temp        = 0;
    int _result     = sum(temp, 3);
    return 0;
}

int sum(int &sum, int *array)
{

}
```

But, my program have a error for declaration, it don't know declare "&" for function
 `int sum(int&, int*);`

How do you fix this problem?

Comment: References are non-existent in C. Pass by pointer instead.

Comment: And call sum with 3 as second parameter does not make sense.

Comment: This is not C code. C does not have references. If you are programming in C++, please specify C++ instead of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. References are not available in [c](/questions/tagged/c)
2. Second parameter calling sum does not make sense.

I guess you want something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int*, int*, int);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int array[]     = {1,2,3};
    int temp        = 0;
    int result     = sum(&temp, array, 3);
    return 0;
}

int sum(int *sum, int *array, int array_size)
{
    // sum stuff
    return *sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

References do not exist in C as they do in C++.
If you want indirect access to some object you will do it through a pointer which holds an address to an object.

To accept arguments in a C function you declare a function like this:
`T foo( T *bar)`, where T is a type. This declaration says that you have to pass a pointer as argument to that function.

When calling a function that accepts pointers as arguments you do it like this:
`T result = foo(&arg)` (here we assume that too returns an object of type T).
We pass arguments like `&arg`, because a pointer as it is will accept a memory address; operator `&` returns an address of an object.

Your confusion might come from the fact that pointers can access values indirectly; by using operator `*` or dereference operator which returns the content hold at the address held by the pointer.